# Importing excel file into a dataframe, causing change in values

Tags: python, pandas, floating-point, truncate, xlsxwriter

I am reading an excel file into pandas data frame. 
The problem I am facing is when I import the file, a value of **0.021893287** becomes **3.7218587899996434e-05** in the data frame. 
And a value of **0.055100** becomes **0.05510000000000001** in the data frame.

Also, I have to do the data calculations in the data frame and then write the data frame into an excel.

After the calculation, I have to truncate the values upto 8 decimal points.

For now, I am converting all the numeric columns to string format and then slicing the string. However, I am still facing issues when I see the results, as some of the results are still getting converted to Exponential format.

Example 1 :
[image]

Result 1 :
[image]

Example 2 :
[image]

Result 2 :
[image]

Note: Fund name and CUSIP in Excel sheet picture had been edited earlier. Please ignore it.

Comment: you may want to check `pd.options.display.float_format` for formatting options

Comment: First, is “a value of 0.021893287 becomes 3.7218587899996434e-05” a typo or copy-paste error? Was it actually that something like “.0000372186” bvecomes “3.7218587899996434e-05”. If not, then you have some communication or data format error, not a floating-point problem. Other than that, the issues you report seem consistent with merely different **displays** of numerical data, not actual changes in value. In that case, you likely ought to ignore the changes in display. Python/Pandas may use different display formats than Excel, but that does not mean the actual numbers changed.…

Comment: … In such case, the proper procedure is simply to do all the calculations and write the results back to an Excel file. If particular display formatting is desired for the user, that can be set in the Excel file.